# How does one send chat message from chat bot to clients?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, xmpp

I have made a bot which can reply when the client sends a message. I want to send a message to the client without them sending me a message. I don't want to code in each and every message. Can someone please suggest a method for this? Thank you.

```
XMPPService xmpps = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
Message msg = xmpps.parseMessage(req);
.....
......
msg = new MessageBuilder()
    .withRecipientJids(jid)
    .withBody(respMsg)
    .build();
xmpps.sendMessage(msg);
```

what the above code does is, it sends the message after it receives a  message from the client. my bot basically informs the clients about important announcements. so suppose i want to tell them something important without them asking. i just want to send a message and all my clients should receive it. do i need the JID of my clients? if so, then how do i get them? i am new to xmpp please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: i dont get correct answers to my questions.....

Comment: You ask really vague questions.  If you've already figured out how to send messages to the client, why is it so hard to send another message after that?  People probably don't understand your questions.  Post a *short* code example of what you're trying to do and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: i searched a lot and cudnt get it. sure i will put some code :)

Comment: @dragonx-the problem is, i want to send a message even when i don't receive one.

Comment: Hey you have to store the jid's, if you want to send messages without receiving any you need to have the Jid's. so one way would be to store all the Jid's in the object store when the client sends a request to the app the first time.

Comment: how do i send the message? as in now, i have a condition in the code which checks whether its the admins email id. if yes then it sends the message to all clients. is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to broadcast messages to all jou xmpp contacts at once. You have to adress them one by one. If you look deepher in the xmpp code you will see that status updates will be broadcasted to all contacts that are not offline. Maybe you can use that to your advantage.